# hide RecyclerView when item clicked in the list and get the clicked address

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-places-api

placeResult can give me the lat and lng of the clicked location but how to get the actually address shown in the list? thanks for helps

public class MainContentFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener{

```
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final LatLngBounds myBounds = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));

EditText mAutocompleteView;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
ImageView delete;

public MainContentFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_content, container, false);

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mAutocompleteView = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_tv);
    delete = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.clear_text);
    mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.searchview_adapter, mGoogleApiClient, myBounds, null);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }else if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    final PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                    final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                    Log.i("TAG", "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
                    /*
                    Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                     */

                    final PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                    placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                            if(places.getCount()==1){
                                //Do the things here on Click.....
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                    Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                }
            })
    );

    return  v;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
        Log.v("Google API","Connecting");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        Log.v("Google API","Dis-Connecting");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Done");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Suspended");
    Log.v("Code", String.valueOf(i));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==delete){
        mAutocompleteView.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.v("Google API Callback","Connection Failed");
    Log.v("Error Code", String.valueOf(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: nevermind, I solved it

Comment: Then you should add an answer to this post explaining how you solved it so that other people with the same problem can learn from you.

Comment: In OnResult method, just set text to edittext by calling settext(item.description) to retrive address you clicked. But anyone knows how to hide recyclerview after I clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following methods to retrieve data from a `Place`:

`getName()` – The place's name.

`getAddress()` – The place's address, in human-readable format.

`getID()` – The textual identifier for the place. Read more about place IDs in the rest of this page.

`getPhoneNumber()` – The place's phone number.

`getWebsiteUri()` – The URI of the place's website, if known. This is the website maintained by the business or other entity associated with the place. Returns null if no website is known.

`getLatLng()` – The geographical location of the place, specified as latitude and longitude coordinates.

`getViewport()` – A viewport, returned as a LatLngBounds object, useful for displaying the place on a map. May return null if the size of the place is not known.

`getLocale()` – The locale for which the name and address are localized.
getPlaceTypes() – A list of place types that characterize this place. For a list of available place types, see the documentation for the Place interface.

`getPriceLevel()` – The price level for this place, returned as an integer with values ranging from 0 (cheapest) to 4 (most expensive).

`getRating()` – An aggregated rating of the place, returned as a float with values ranging from 1.0 to 5.0, based on aggregated user reviews.

find more details here https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details